# Backup Server using Greyhole and BackupPC

Tags: ubuntu, mount, symbolic-link, backuppc

I'm setting up an Ubuntu box to backup one of our servers using BackupPC. I've got 2x 2tb hard drives and I've set up [Greyhole](http://www.greyhole.net/) to duplicate the data from the samba share /mnt/samba/backups across both drives incase of failure.

I need to set BackupPC to use /mnt/samba/backups as its topdir location, ensuring that all data is backed up across the greyhole pool.

I don't really know much about symlinks or mounting so I tried each set of commands in [Sourceforge's BackupPC wiki article](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/backuppc/index.php?title=Change_archive_directory), checked if it worked, then moved onto the next set of commands. I've also tried changing the topdir location in BackupPC's config.pl file.

I think I've tried every combination of changing/not changing the config.pl topdir location and each of the methods in the wiki article.

Every time I've tried to start BackupPC after any of these changes I receive the following error message:

```
Can't create a test hardlink between a file in /mnt/samba/backups/pc and /mnt/samba/backups/cpool.  Either these are different file systems, or this file system doesn't support hardlinks, or these directories don't exist, or there is a permissions problem, or the file system is out of inodes or full.  Use df, df -i, and ls -ld to check each of these possibilities. Quitting...
```

I'm basically really stuck now. I've chosen to use Greyhole instead of RAID1 over LVM and there isn't enough space left on the main partition to store a full backup. This is the last step I need to configure to complete my setup.

**UPDATE**

**After trying many potential solutions and going over and over the same steps many times I found a forum post stating that you cannot use a Samba share for the BackupPC pool, because Samba shares don't support the hardlinks that BackupPC uses for its pooling feature.**

**So basically if anyone else is stuck on the same issue, don't use BackupPC with Greyhole as Greyhole requires you to locally mount using a Samba share it can't work with BackupPC.**